# The difference between ‘provide for’ and ‘provide with’?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

1. He has provided for every emergency.
2. The old woman provided me with further facts.

What is the difference between ‘provide for’ and ‘provide with’?

Comment: Have you checked any online dictionaries?

Comment: @Cardinal I checked. I know ‘provide something for sb’. So, I feel sentence 1 is weird.

Comment: So, your question in its current format is not very clear. Would you explain what is the intended question about those two sentences?

Comment: @Cardinal According to my checking, I think sentence 1 is wrong. So I want to know If sentence 1 is true. If sentence 1 is true, what is the difference between sentence 1 and 2? If sentence 1 is wrong, is it need to use ‘provide with’ in sentence 1 like sentence 2?

Comment: @Cardinal I just see it in my book, and I feel it is weird.

Comment: OK, I think that's correct! "provide for something" means " to make plans in order to deal with a possible event in the future" from Cambridge.dictionary. So, 1 means he is kind of ready for the emergency events.